# REGEX: Python vs. SED Replace the FQDN of a URL but preserve port

Tags: python, regex, sed

TL;DR:  I'm trying to change the FQDN of a URL but keep the port using python's re.sub.

Example Input:

```
http://www.yahoo.com:80/news.html
http://new.news.com/news.html
https://www.ya.com:443/new.html
https://www.yahoots.com/new.html
```

Example Output:

```
http://www.google.com:80/news.html
http://www.google.com/news.html
https://www.google.com:443/new.html
https://www.google.com/new.html
```

And here's my sample code that is producing the output:

```
sed -e 's|//[^:]*\(:[0-9]*\)*/|//www.google.com\1/|'  < input
```

That seems to work fine.  In short, I'm looking to replace everything between the // and the next /, but I want to keep the port (if specified) in tact.

However, the python version doesn't work so well:

```
re.sub( '//.*(:[0-9]*)*/' , '//' + 'www.google.com\\1' + '/' , 'http://www.yahoo.com/news.m3u8' )
```

Yields:

```
sre_constants.error: unmatched group
```

However it works if the port is present:

```
re.sub( '//.*(:[0-9]*)*/' , '//' + 'www.google.com\\1' + '/' , 'http://www.yahoo.com:80/news.m3u8' )
```

Should be simple, but I figured this would hopefully spark a useful discussion as to how sed and python use different regex expressions.  At the very least, someone smarter than me can tell me what I'm doing wrong.  I've considered avoiding the problem entirely by restructuring the program or using a url parsing library, but I am curious as to what is up with python's regex.  I am also worried that  `(:` has some special meaning to python re library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But if you are using Python 2 or just want to use a Regex:

```
import re

url = 'http://www.yahoo.com:80/news.html'
new_url = re.sub(r'(?<=://)(.*?)(?=[:/])', 'www.google.com', url)
print new_url
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the right tool for the right job.  `urlparse` is that tool.

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse #python 3

url = 'http://www.yahoo.com:80/news.html'
url = urlparse(url)
url = url._replace(netloc="{}:{}".format('www.google.com', url.port)) # Mark's edit
print(url.geturl()) # Mark's edit
```

**EDIT:**  Recently (July 6 2023) I tried this code and found that the _replace() function returns a new [ParseResult](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html) (leaving the current one unmutated).  I've added an assignment to line before the print to update this code.  I've also added the () to print for python3 reasons.  Maybe the new _replace() behavior is a python2/python3 difference as well (please excuse the lack of additional research I should have done).